# Error 9: Bad file descriptor while transferring a single file in python

Tags: python, sockets, client-server

I am trying to send a file and receive it on localhost using a single port. 
I keep on getting this error 9 :Bad file descriptor although I tried everything!

Here is the file send code:

```
import socket                   # Import socket module
port = 60000                    # Reserve a port for your service.
s = socket.socket()             # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname()     # Get local machine name
s.connect((host, port))
while True:
     filename='mytext.txt'
     f = open(filename,'rb')
     l = f.read(1024)
     while (l):
        s.send(l)
        print('Sent ',repr(l))
        l = f.read(1024)
     f.close()
print('Done sending')
s.close()
```

Here is file receive code:

```
import socket                   # Import socket module
s = socket.socket()             # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname()     # Get local machine name
port = 60000                    # Reserve a port for your service.
s.bind((host, port))            # Bind to the port
s.listen(5)                     # Now wait for client connection.
print 'Listening....'

with open('received_file', 'wb') as f:
    print 'file opened'

while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
    print 'Got connection from', addr
    print('receiving data...')
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    print('data=%s', (data))
    if not data:
        break
    # write data to a file
    f.write(data)
f.close()
print('Successfully get the file')
print('connection closed')
```

Error I get:

```
('Sent ', "'Hello world!!!!!'")
Done sending
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-ef0f47f9369f> in <module>()
     22      l = f.read(1024)
     23      while (l):
---> 24         s.send(l)
     25         print('Sent ',repr(l))
     26         l = f.read(1024)

C:\Users\Samir\Anaconda2\lib\socket.pyc in _dummy(*args)
    172     __slots__ = []
    173     def _dummy(*args):
--> 174         raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
    175     # All _delegate_methods must also be initialized here.
    176     send = recv = recv_into = sendto = recvfrom = recvfrom_into = 
_dummy

error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your client you are re-sending the contents infinite times, so drop the outer `while` loop.

It could just be:

```
with open('mytext.txt', 'rb') as f:
    l = f.read(1024)
    while l:
        s.send(l)
        print 'Sent ', repr(l)
        l = f.read(1024)
```

Your server has issues as well and probably the reason for the error as it crashes when reading the input data. You are opening a file descriptor and then closing it before the loop because you are using a context manager.

You should probably create a new file every time a client connects:

```
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
    print 'Got connection from', addr
    print 'receiving data...'
    with open('received_file', 'wb') as f:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        print 'data=%s', (data)
        if not data:
            break
            # write data to a file
        f.write(data)
```

It will of course just overwrite the same file, but I'm sure you can figure that out.

This is my no means perfect code, but it works. Remember that when using the `with` statement you are creating a context manager that will automatically close the file no matter how the code is exiting the block.

Your server is also just reading the first 1024 bytes of the file, but you can figure that out. If you are planning to send larger content it can be a good idea to boost the buffer size up to 64kb.

Comment: Thanks! I couldnt solve this for hours!! But wont deleting the outer while loop mean I am no longer waiting on connection?

Comment: make sure you fix your server as well!

Comment: @SamT01 The outer loop was removed in the client, not the server